# C: display colored output to console not working

Tags: c, output-formatting

I am using Xcode and trying to display colored output to the console. it isn't working and I don't know why, I've looked at other stack overflow posts and tried the code that works.
help is appreciated!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\x1b[0m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN "\x1b[36m"


void dispWrongs(char guess, int wordLength);

int main(void) {
        srand(time(NULL));            //sends a "seed" for random number generation
   
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_CYAN "                       _        _            \n");
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_CYAN "  ___ ___  _   _ _ __ | |_ _ __(_) ___  ___  \n");
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_CYAN " / __/ _ \\| | | | '_ \\| __| '__| |/ _ \\/ __\\ \n");
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_CYAN "| (_| (_) | |_| | | | | |_| |  | |  __/\\__ \\ \n");
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_CYAN " \\___\\___/ \\__,_|_| |_|\\__|_|  |_|\\___||___/"ANSI_COLOR_RESET"\n");
  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code should work. But make sure your terminal support this. So, what terminal do you use?

Comment: what do you mean by terminal?  I am using Xcode

Comment: It is entirely likely that XCode's built-in output window does not support ANSI color codes.  When people say "Terminal" they refer to the command-line interface of the operating system where you interact with the Shell.  On Mac OSX, there is even a built-in program called Terminal.  Maybe start by running your program there.

Comment: These string `"\x1b[..."` are control sequences to the piece of software that makes your output visible, which is commonly called "terminal" because it is the terminal end of data transfer. And so this piece of software has to interpret these strings and set the color or do whatever the sequence is supposed to mean. If the software does not support these sequences, you will not see the desired effect, in your case, colors.

Answer (score 1):

You're using VT/ANSI codes. For that to work, make sure you run the application in a terminal window that supports this.

The macOS Terminal app is in the Utilities folder in Applications.

But if you want a smarter way of displaying colors you should use a curses library (like ncurses), as it will detect the right way to display color for the type of terminal you are using to run the application.